# How to redirect from one ec2 instance to another ec2 instance if first ec2 instance is down?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hope you are doing well.

I have created website in Laravel framework and deployed on AWS EC2 server. If Ec2 instance is down sometimes how I redirect user to another ec2 instance created for different region how to achieve this using aws service ?

I have one more question what are aws security service I can use for my website  ?

Waiting for your reply

Thanks

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: AWS Route53 can do exactly what you are asking for in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide immediately failover, then you will need to **run multiple Amazon EC2 instances**. That way, if one instance becomes unresponsive, then the other instance can handle requests.

If you are going to run multiple instances, it actually makes more sense to **have both instances responding to requests at all times**, since they can handle twice the load. Then, if one instance fails, the remaining instance can still handle the load.

There are a few services that can assist with this...

[Elastic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html) can **distribute incoming traffic across multiple target instances**. It also performs Health Checks and can automatically stop sending traffic to instances that stop responding.

[Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html) can monitor EC2 instances and **automatically replace failed instances** with new instances. (It terminates the bad instance and then launches a new instance.)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and nice explanation. @John Rotenstein